# Plotting BSpline curves in C++/Octave

Tags: c++, math, octave, spline

This might be a stupid question. I have an Octave and C++

And I want to plot BSpline curves. Unfortunately, I can't find the necessary packages. Does anyone have any idea how I can plot BSplines somehow. Sorry, but I searched the internet in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the code mentioned at following url, hope this will help :
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=9222&lngWId=3